# On The Biggest Loser, do they interview contestants before AND after the weekly weigh-in?

Tags: production, editing

Each week on The Biggest Loser, during the weekly weigh-in segment, the show will frequently cut back and forth between contestant interviews and the weigh-in itself as it progresses. The contestants narrate a lot of the "drama" of the weigh-in by sharing their anticipation before the results are revealed, and reactions after.

Since the contestants are (presumably) not actors, I'm trying to figure out how they pull this off. Do they film interviews before the weigh-in, asking about how they're feeling going into it, and also after, asking about the results? (Otherwise, I'd expect that non-actors wouldn't be able to reliably answer questions about their anticipation of the results, if they already know what the results are.)

I've watched the show carefully, and it doesn't **look** like a separate interview, but I can't tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In this AMA session](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/zakkz/i_ama_former_biggest_loser_contestant_who_would/), a former contestant revealed that the whole weigh-in session takes a very long time, with multiple parts being redone. He couldn't reveal too much detail as he was legally obligated not to. An interesting part that he *did* reveal was that they were trained to always speak in the present tense during interviews. So my educated guess given all these bits of info is that the producers do multiple interviews before and after the actual weigh-in.